# Django + Celery + Nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, celery

I try to run my django application in docker with Celery and Nginx.

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
  helpdesk_web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: helpdesk_web
    volumes:
      - ./static:/usr/src/app/static
      - media:/usr/src/app/media
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "5678:5678"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - helpdesk_db
      - helpdesk_redis

  helpdesk_db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: helpdesk_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: helpdesk_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: itds
      POSTGRES_USER: itds

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: helpdesk_nginx
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - helpdesk_web
      - helpdesk_db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/usr/src/app/static
      - media:/usr/src/app/media
  
  helpdesk_redis:
    image: redis
    ports: 
      - "6379:6379"
  
  helpdesk_celery:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery -A helpdesk worker -l INFO --pool=solo
    depends_on:
      - helpdesk_web
      - helpdesk_redis
  
  helpdesk_celery-beat:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery -A helpdesk beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
    depends_on:
      - helpdesk_web
      - helpdesk_redis

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  media:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10


WORKDIR /usr/src/app


ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip


COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."
    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done
    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi
python manage.py migrate --no-input
exec gunicorn helpdesk.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=$WORKERS_COUNT
```

When I run docker-compose I get that error [image]

I have dev docker-compose without nginx and it works fine. It seems that there are some problems between celery and nginx. I am a beginner to docker so I don't know what to do.

What am I missing?

EDIT №1:
It's like celery and celery-beat are set as gunicorn.
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're passing in  an environment variable `$WORKERS_COUNT` but the value isn't present so you're passing an empty string ('') into the `--workers` flag. Remove that flag or set the environment variable.

Comment: @rob thank you, sir. I could run my app but now celery doesn't run properly and doesn't execute tasks. I will attach a screen in edit.

Answer (score 0):

The Compose `command:` overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`, and is [passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  A typical setup is to have your entrypoint script do first-time setup, like waiting for a database, but then end with the special shell command `exec "$@"` to run the command passed to it as arguments.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# Wait for the database, run migrations, set environment variables, ...
if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]; then ...; fi
python manage.py migrate --no-input

# Run the command passed as arguments, not a fixed command here
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile declare the default `CMD` you want the container to run, like GUnicorn.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD gunicorn helpdesk.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=$WORKERS_COUNT
```

Now it will honor the Compose `command:`, or another command you `docker-compose run`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports: ['8000:8000', '5678:5678']
    env_file: [.env]
    restart: always
    depends_on: [db, redis]
    # and the default image CMD
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A helpdesk worker -l INFO --pool=solo
    depends_on: [redis]
  celery-beat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A helpdesk beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
    depends_on: [redis]
  db: { ... }
  redis: { image: redis }
```